# C Kernel - Works fine on VM but not actual computer?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, kernel, hex

I am making a basic C kernel. (Loaded by an assembly program) I am compiling it with an i686-elf cross compiler for windows. My C code is as follows:

```
void cls();
void drawhappy();
void main(){
    char *vidptr = (char *)0xb8000;
    cls();
    drawhappy();
}

void cls(){
    char *vidptr = (char *)0xb8000;
    unsigned int j = 0;
    while(j < 80*2*25){
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;
        j = j+2;
    }
}

void drawhappy(){
    char *vidptr = (char *)0xb8000;
    const unsigned int linewidth = 80*2;
    vidptr[3] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[5] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[7] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[9] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[1+linewidth] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[5+linewidth] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[7+linewidth] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[11+linewidth] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[1+linewidth*2] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[3+linewidth*2] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[5+linewidth*2] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[7+linewidth*2] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[9+linewidth*2] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[11+linewidth*2] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[1+linewidth*3] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[5+linewidth*3] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[7+linewidth*3] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[11+linewidth*3] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[1+linewidth*4] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[11+linewidth*4] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[3+linewidth*5] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[5+linewidth*5] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[7+linewidth*5] = 0xa7;
    vidptr[9+linewidth*5] = 0xa7;
}
```

In bochs, it gives me the expected output:
[image: Yay]
And if I use bootice to write the bin file to the boot sector and run it as a VM on virtualbox, it works too. But if I actually boot from the USB stick, It just kinda goes crazy then puts a weird symbol by the bottom right corner of my screen. (No screenshot because I obviously can't) I have an i7-3770K CPU. Why is this happening?

EDIT: Here's my assembly code:

```
[org 0x7c00]
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE
    call print_string

    call load_kernel

    call switch_to_pm

jmp $

%include "C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/CODE_OS/print_string.asm"
; load DH sectors to ES:BX from drive DL
disk_load:
    push dx

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, dh
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02

    int 0x13

    jc disk_error

    pop dx
    cmp dh, al
    jne disk_error
    ret

disk_error:
    mov bx, DISK_ERROR_MSG
    call print_string
    jmp $

DISK_ERROR_MSG: db "Disk read error!", 0
%include "C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/CODE_OS/print_string_pm.asm"
%include "C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/CODE_OS/switch_to_pm.asm"
; GDT
gdt_start:

gdt_null:   ; the mandatory null descriptor
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

gdt_code:   ; the code segment descriptor
    dw 0xffff   ; limit
    dw 0x0      ; base
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start

[bits 16]

load_kernel:
    mov bx, MSG_LOAD_KERNEL
    call print_string

    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    mov dh, 15
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_load

    ret

[bits 32]

BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE
    call print_string_pm

    call KERNEL_OFFSET

    jmp $

BOOT_DRIVE db 0
MSG_REAL_MODE  db 'Started in 16-bit Real Mode',0
MSG_PROT_MODE db 'Successfully booted to 32-bit Protected Mode',0
MSG_LOAD_KERNEL db "Loading Kernel...",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; Pad the boot sector out with zeros
dw 0xaa55 ; Last two bytes form the magic number
```

(Print-string.asm just prints strings, switch_to_pm.asm switches to protected mode, and print_string_pm.asm prints strings in protected mode.)

Comment: Have your explicitly set the video mode in previous stages? Do you actually have a BIOS on your computer, or just an emulated one?

Comment: It's unclear how you want to boot this, as it is a protected mode ELF image and the classical boot sector is run in 16 bit real mode. You need some boot loader (such as grub) or maybe firmware that understands it.

Comment: I have UEFI, so does that mean it's emulated? @user35443

Comment: So you haven't written any bootloader code or such?

Comment: @Jester But then why can I boot it as a VM on virtualbox?

Comment: @user35443 I wrote an assembly program to load the kernel.

Comment: I guess it was 32-bit, so you weren't able to set the video mode, right?

Comment: Well, you haven't showed that assembly program. Presumably it's assuming something that's not true on your real machine. Frequently that concerns the load address being `0:7c00` or `7c0:0`.

Comment: @user35443 Yes, it is 32 bit.

Comment: @Jester I added my assembly code to my post.

Comment: There you go, it's hardwired for `0:7c00` but the code may be loaded at `7c0:0` (which is the same physical address of course). You also don't initialize `DS` at all. You should add code to set up `CS` and `DS`.

Comment: @Jester May I ask, what to CS and DS stand for?

Comment: @Jester, do you think the video mode could be set to something different than the default one?

Comment: @Jester Or do you just think I should use grub?

Comment: CS=code segment, DS=data segment. They are two of the four segment registers, the others being SS=stack segment, and ES=extra segment.

Comment: @user3386109 Okay, thanks. Do you think I should just use grub, though?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with grub, so Jester will have to help you with that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing the segment registers. Try changing the start of your bootsector to something like this:

```
xor ax, ax
mov bp, 0x9000
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax ; disables interrupts until the end of the next instruction
mov sp, bp
mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
```

Comment: Minimal examples with exact compilation steps at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples I faced a similar problem at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508919/how-to-produce-a-minimal-bios-hello-world-boot-sector-with-gcc-that-works-from-a